# How do I make RTL for ionRangeSlider?

Tags: javascript

There is a calculator that is implemented through the Ion Range Slider, so it needs to be remade for RTL (Arabic spelling, from right to left).

Here is a demo - `https://codepen.io/ruslan-lysenko/pen/WNGGVRY`

See the Pen WNGGVRY by Руслан Лысенко
  (@ruslan-lysenko) on CodePen.

Tried to use this crutch which was advised on github but it didn't help - `jsfiddle.net/IonDen/gbmszmp4`

```
    var $range = $(".js-range-slider"),
  min = -30,
  max = 70;

$range.ionRangeSlider({
  type: "single",
  min: min,
  max: max,
  from: 30,
  prettify: function(num) {
    var tmp_min = min,
      tmp_max = max,
      tmp_num = num;

    if (min < 0) {
      tmp_min = 0;
      tmp_max = max - min;
      tmp_num = num - min;
      tmp_num = tmp_max - tmp_num;
      return tmp_num + min;
    } else {
      num = max - num;
      return num;
    }
  }
});
```

How to solve a problem?

Thanks.

Comment: you should copy your code in stackover flow instead of codepen

Comment: @Abilogos , I am pasting but cannot save. Writes that the character limit has been exhausted. And I can't throw off half of the code, nothing will be clear.

Comment: you have to edit your question and pate the code there, not here.

Comment: @Abilogos, I do not understand at all what you want from me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably are over this already, but I checked the github repo for solutions by searching the issues:
https://github.com/IonDen/ion.rangeSlider/issues?q=RTL

Then found a lot of broken workarounds.

Except this one, which seems to work in the browser:
https://codepen.io/mostafaznv/pen/BayemoP

```
// See below
```

```js
function fixPosition(slider, fromPercent) {
  let w;
  
  if(fromPercent === 100) {
    w = 'calc(100% - 24px)';
  }
  else {
    w = 'calc(' + fromPercent + '% - 12px)';
  }
  
  slider.find('.irs-bar').css('left', 'auto').css('width', w);
  slider.find('.irs-handle').css('left', 'auto').css('right', w);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  let min = 1;
  let max = 10;
  
  $(".js-range-slider").ionRangeSlider({
    type: 'single',
    skin: 'round',
    min: min,
    max: max,
    grid: true,
    grid_snap: true,
    grid_margin: false,
    hide_min_max: true,
    hide_from_to: true,
    
    onStart: function (data) {
      fixPosition(data.slider, 0);
    },
    
    onChange: function (data) {
      data.from = min + (max - data.from);
      data.from_percent = 100 - data.from_percent;
      
      fixPosition(data.slider, data.from_percent);
    },
    
    prettify: function(num) {
      num = min + (max - num);
      return num;
    }
  });
  
  $('#range-slide-get-value').click(function() {
    let value = $('#range-slider').val();
    
    $('#range-slide-value').text(value);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  direction: rtl;
  padding: 50px;
}

.irs--round .irs-handle {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
}

.irs-bar {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
}

.irs--round .irs-line,
.irs--round .irs-bar {
  top: 33px;
  height: 9px;
}

.irs--round .irs-bar--single {
    border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}

#range-slide-get-value {
  background-color: #006cfa;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.3.1/css/ion.rangeSlider.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.3.1/js/ion.rangeSlider.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="js-range-slider" id="range-slider" name="range"/>

<br><br>
  
<button id="range-slide-get-value">Get Value</button>
<p id="range-slide-value"></p>
```